What could be causing a hang up when initializing Firestore in java?
I've been trying to set up Firestore in our java application but the application keeps hanging. Here is the code:
public FirestoreDB(AppPlugin plugin) {
    this.plugin = plugin;
    try {
        Anpr.getLogger().info("App: Initializing FirestoreDB...");
        serviceAccount = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(FIREBASE_ADMIN));
        Anpr.getLogger().fine("App: Got service account file.");
        credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount);
        Anpr.getLogger().fine("App: Got credentials.");
        options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                .setCredentials(credentials)
                .build();
        Anpr.getLogger().fine("App: Got options.");
        firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        Anpr.getLogger().fine("App: FirebaseApp initialized.");
        db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore(firebaseApp);
        Anpr.getLogger().info("App: FirestoreDB initialized.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Anpr.getLogger().severe("App: Error initializing FirestoreDB.");
        Anpr.getLogger().fine(Utils.PrintException(e));
    }
}

The program consistently makes it to the "App: Got credentials." line but then after that there's nothing, not even an error. It simply hangs. This is the exact same set up we have in a different application and it works flawlessly there.
I've tried many things to get past, such as using default instances, FirestoreOptions, and skipping it all entirely and calling FirestoreClient.getFirestore() directly. None of it works, it just continously hangs.
Here is my gradle.build file:
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile project(':anprcore')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.8.1'
    compile 'com.google.api:api-common:1.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.11.0'
    compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:0.61.0-beta'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.25.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.25.0'


    testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.2.0'
    testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.2.0'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    }
}


test {
//    useJUnitPlatform()
}

task copyJar(type: Copy, dependsOn: jar) {
    from 'build/libs/appplugin.jar'
    into '../anprcore/lib/'
}

build.dependsOn {
    copyJar
}

I am aware that all of the libraries I have here are quite outdated, we have quite a lot of legacy stuff elsewhere in the program, and I am not skilled enough to go through all the conflict resolution to update everything. These are also the exact versions of everything that we have in the working application (the build file is practically a copy paste).
Any help would be much appreciated.
